# Compiler Error: "error CS0307: The variable 'int' cannot be used with type arguments"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors

If I have the following code:

```
private void Check(bool a, bool b)
{
}

private void Check(int a, int b, int c, bool flag)
{
    Check(a < b, a > (flag ? c : b - 10));
}
```

I get a compile-time error on the call to `Check(int, int)`:

> error CS0307: The variable 'int' cannot be used with type arguments

I also get these errors:

> error CS0118: 'b' is a variable but is used like a type
>   error CS0118: 'a' is a variable but is used like a type

Why do these errors occur? What is wrong with the code?

Comment: I had to add parenthesis: `Check((a<b), a>(flag ? c : b - 10));`, I don't know why though, *shrug*. edit: also, without parenthesis, `>` and `==` works fine: `Check(a==b, a>(flag ? c : b - 10));`, `Check(a > b, a > (flag ? c : b - 10));`. Must be some `<` related operator?

Comment: @Quantic  `Check(a<b,a> (flag ? c : b - 10));` function a with generic arguments  `<b,a>`

Comment: @L.B yep that's it, `Check(a<b, a < (flag ? c : b - 10));` works fine (reversed the `>` to `<` so it doesn't look like a generic method any more).

Comment: @L.B True, but the question is why. Sounds like a bug?

Comment: @IvanStoev Hard to guess why compiler writers have chosen  this way....

Comment: @L.B It's actually because of the opening parenthesis in addition to the `<a,b>` making it look like a generic method call. So I wouldn't say it's a bug because looking again: `a<b,a>(flag ? c : b - 10)` is "Function `a` with type arguments `b, a` and integer parameter `flag ? c : b - 10`", and passing a method around instead of assigning the return value better be supported, right? Remove those parenthesis and it also works fine: `int someInt = flag ? c : b - 10; Check(a<b, a > someInt);`

Comment: I ran into this compiler error when there was a missing "Project Reference" in the solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a great day for me. I never thought I would see one of these in the wild! I have only ever seen this in compiler test cases.

Consider the following program fragment:

```
F(G<A,B>(7));
```

In C# 1.0, that meant "call method F with two arguments: `G<A` and `B>(7)`.

But C# 2.0 added generics. In C# 2.0 this means "call method F with one argument. The argument is a call to generic method `G<A, B>` with one argument, 7".

This was a breaking change.  C# has some heuristics to try to ensure that old programs that match this pattern keep working, but not all of them do.

C# is interpreting your program

```
Check(a < b, a > (flag ? c : b - 10));
```

as a call to `Check` with one argument: a call to generic method `a<b, a>` with one argument.

The solution for you is simple, as you have discovered: simply put in more parentheses to separate the arguments to Check.

If you are interested to know the exact rule C# uses to try to tell when it is generic and when it is not, it is:

> If a sequence of tokens can be parsed as a simple-name, member-access, or pointer-member-access ending with a type-argument-list, the token immediately following the closing > token is examined. If it is one of `(  )  ]  }  :  ;  ,  .  ?  ==  !=  |  ^` then the type-argument-list is retained as part of the simple-name, member-access or pointer-member-access and any other possible parse of the sequence of tokens is discarded. Otherwise, the type-argument-list is not considered to be part of the simple-name, member-access or pointer-member-access, even if there is no other possible parse of the sequence of tokens. Note that these rules are not applied when parsing a type-argument-list in a namespace-or-type-name.

Having to implement rules like this makes C# a *little bit tricky* to parse, believe me.

Comment: *This is a great day for me...* reminds me something like this: *if you see a person walking on the street in a cold rainy day and smiling, that could only be a weatherman whose forecast has come true* :) Just kidding, great post as usual!