# VS 2017 Bug or new features?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-7.0

After upgrading to VS 2017 I got the following error from this code (which has always been working perfectly)

```
byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
            throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

        byte[] arr = new byte[hex.Length >> 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length >> 1; ++i) // Error in this line
        {
            arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

Exception:

```
Error 1: The variable 'i' cannot be used with type arguments
Error 2: 'hex' is a variable but is used like a type
```

the solution was to surround the expression by parentheses.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (hex.Length >> 1); ++i)
```

But that made me wonder is this a bug or a new functionality?
Thanks.

Comment: whatever it is the solution looks much cleaner code.

Comment: That's a bug, pretty big one.  [It belongs here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues), click the New Issue button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler Error: "error CS0307: The variable 'int' cannot be used with type arguments"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669720/compiler-error-error-cs0307-the-variable-int-cannot-be-used-with-type-argum)

Comment: @NineBerry Unless the OP was using C# 1.0 before upgrading to VS2017, I'm not sure that's a suitable dupe target.

Comment: For anyone interested, [this has been logged as an issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17626).

Comment: Ooh, a bug! A nice one too.

Comment: @JamesThorpe The explanation given in the other issue remains the same. The C# 7.0 Compiler just seems to have changed the heuristic that is used to decide when to interpret text as a Generic rather than as a comparison expression.

Comment: @NineBerry: not a dupe; as the answer to that question describes, this particular parsing is an error when following the spec since the token following `>` (namely another `>`) is not one of the list that allow an interpretation as a type argument list. "The compiler simply changed the heuristic" would be valid if the compiler dictated the language, but even if you think it does, the question is still not a duplicate. It's good reference material, though.

Comment: As a *completely* unrelated aside, if you want to divide things by 2, write `x / 2`, not `x >> 1`. It's a persistent misconception that bit shifting is "faster" and should therefore be preferred. It's not and it shouldn't. Write what you mean. This is especially true when you mix it up with bit shifts that *are* intended to get at specific bits (like `<< 4` to indicate these will be the upper 4 bits). This would as a happy coincidence also avoid the parser error.

Comment: Thx's for this! Had the exact same issue. (actually the exact same code) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This is a confirmed regression in the precedence of parsing. This fix will ship in the first quarterly release of VS2017 at the latest.

Information on the fix: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/16834